html_nodes always return {xml_nodeset (0)}
I'm trying to scrape this page with the rvest R package: https://www.bienici.com/recherche/achat/dessin-669cc780ec9a6600b7687ce8/2-pieces?prix-max=260000&surface-min=40&surface-max=55&neuf=non&mode=liste&tri=publication-desc
But I can't retrieve the elements by id, class or Xpath, the results is always {xml_nodeset (0)}. I don't know why habitually it works well.

library(dplyr)
library(rvest)

url <- 'https://www.bienici.com/recherche/achat/dessin-669cc780ec9a6600b7687ce8/2-pieces?prix-max=260000&surface-min=40&surface-max=55&neuf=non&mode=liste&tri=publication-desc'

# for example getting the h3 title of each result
url %>% 
    read_html %>% 
    html_nodes('h3')

# or by Xpath
url %>% 
    read_html %>% 
    html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@id="searchResults"]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/article[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/a/div[2]/div[1]/h3/span[1]')


Yeah, the entire page is loaded via Javascript which read_html doesn't step through. If you look at the contents of the page you pulled down, the only thing in it is an h1 object with the text "Il est nécessaire d'activer Javascript dans les paramètres de votre navigateur pour accéder à ce site". You may need to look into RSelenium (which is a whole separate rabbit hole) or consider trying to use the paid(?) api available in Python at least: https://apify.com/azzouzana/bienici-com-search-pages-scraper/api/client/python

This question is similar to Web scraping from Uniprot using R and many others where rvest::read_html() is used with javascript-rendered page, try replacing read_html() with  read_html_live()
